# EC2 : SSH with DNS works but not with Public IP

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, dns, ip

I want to connect via ssh from one ec2 machine to another (to use ansible). Something very strange happen.

The command with the DNS works on my machine and on the ec2 machine:

```
ssh -t -i ~/.aws/keypair.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@ec2-54-154-0-12.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

But this command with the public IP works from my own computer but not from the ec2 machine (timeout) :

```
ssh -t -i ~/.aws/keypair.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o User=ubuntu 54.76.190.253
```

Is someone understand why ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated both the Security Groups and ACL's for the incoming server to allow traffic (TCP 22 in this case) from the source machine?

If you are trying to connect from within the same VPC in EC2, then you need to try connecting to the internal IP rather than external if all you have allowed is the internal IP range (the default security group allows for this iirc).

Personally within EC2, I only use internal ranges within the same Region as VPC rules are easier to keep secured given most external IP addresses will dynamically change as you stop/start instances if you don't use elastic IPs on them.

Comment: Hello, the security groups are ok : both instance belongs to the same security groups and this security group allow TCP 22 for itself. Actually the first command relies on a ssh connection with the internal IP and the second one with the external one. But I do not understand why the second command is not working.